# What is the source of the song "Jagadisha Sudisha Bhavesha Vibho"?

Tags: shiva, identification-request

What is the source of the song "Jagadisha Sudisha Bhavesha Vibho"?

Link:- https://m.soundcloud.com/jaisanth/sounds

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Hindusim SE. Please take a [TOUR](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/tour) of this site to get acquainted. Further, kindly visit [How does a new user get started on Hinduism SE?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-hinduism-se). For more info please do visit: [the HSE Help Center](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help). Have an enriching journey!!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.